# Какое это наклонение?

Tags: наклонение

Есть фраза:

> Позвольте поздравить вас с днем рождения.

Позвольте поздравить - это единая форма? Какое это наклонение? Повелительное или изъявительное, по форме напоминающее повелительное?

Comment: Скорее здесь просительное наклонение, чем изъяснительное. Но поскольку просительное объединено в общую группу с приказательным, то в итоге у нас повелительное. "позвольте поздравить" это составное глагольное сказуемое с глаголом связкой, не употребляющейся без содержательного глагола. Более "единая" форма это "давайте поздравим вас", в ней содержательный глагол не в форме инфинитива, а у нас в форме инфинитива, поэтому не единая форма, а стандартное СГС

Comment: Разве такое наклонение есть?

Comment: Зависит от того, какой классификации придерживаться. В стандартной классификации его нет, т.е. оно входит в повелительное

Comment: Но ведь оно не выражает прямого побуждения.

Comment: Ну да. Классифицировать наклонения можно либо по грамматическим признакам (и тогда не важно что чего не выражает), либо по смысловым признакам. Стандартная классификация опирается на грамматические.